# Handle mouse event on irregular shaped objects with event delegation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I need to handle mouse events on a page where there are multiple irregular-shaped objects (for example, houses) are stacked on top of each other. If I use the normal way of event delegation jQuery `.on()`, the event source reported will always be the top most object, even if user clicked on the transparent part of the object (or image).

Example: `<img>` tag that contains the red triangle will always be the event source even if I click at the X position.

[image: Example]

I can detect that mouse click is not inside the triangle. What I need is a way to "forward" the event to the green triangle below.

**EDIT:** My current approach is to catch the events on a big div that wraps everything, then use jQuery selector and compare coordinates to find out which object is under the mouse, then check if the mouse is in transparent part or not. It works fine, but seems to be slow and consume **a lot** of memory, especially with mouse move events being fired continuously.

**EDIT 2:**
This image was extracted from [Building a game engine with jQuery](http://www.slideshare.net/pbakaus/building-a-game-engine-with-jquery), and my approach was almost identical to that. And now, this is the question:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a consistent plug-n-play method of doing this.

Comment: What about using image map and area tags?

Comment: Learn about paper.js, is easy and very powerful (but it works only on new browsers: Chrome, Firefox 3.5+, IE9)

Comment: @IvanCastellanos all my images are bitmap-based.

Comment: It would be very easy to create an invisible canvas (opacity:0) so you can use paperjs to handle events on irregular shapes. And paperjs have support for bitmap images (as fills/backgrounds)

Answer (score 1):

Are you drawing complex graphics using plain HTML elements? Not sure about your exact needs, but it might make more sense to use SVG or Canvas, where catching click events on shapes becomes much easier.